# Calculating the sum of varchar2 data fields in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g

How to use the sum function of SQL to calculate sum of varchar field. I'm looking for a solution where we cannot use count.

Comment: what do you mean "cannot use count"?

Answer (score 3):

If the varchar field contains strings that can be interpreted as numbers:

```
select sum(to_number(the_column)) from the_table
```

If not, I do not understand the question.